# How to make IntelliJ IDEA warn when null might be returned from lambda?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, lambda, nullable

There are very useful code inspections in IntelliJ IDEA *Constant conditions & exceptions* and *Return of 'null'*. They show warnings when a method without `@Nullable` annotation returns `null`, a result of `@Nullable` method, `@Nullable` field or variable which might evaluate to `null`.

Unfortunately, the same not work with lambda expressions. IntelliJ IDEA just ignores possible returning of `null` from them. But I am pretty sure that there is a way to make *Search Template* for *Structural Search Inspection* which will find all possible returnings `null` from lambda expressions.

By this moment I've managed to make a template which finds references to `@Nullable` methods and template that wraps single-line lambdas with a method accepting `@NotNull` generic argument and returning it back, it doesn't change code semantics and shows warnings when lambda might return null.

Here are my templates:

Nullable methods:

```
@Nullable
$MethodType$ $Method$($ParameterType$ $Parameter$);
```

Nullable method references

```
$Qualifier$::$Method$

//Filters for $Method$:
reference = Nullable methods
```

Lambdas with unchecked result:

```
($Parameter$) -> $Statement$

//Filters for $Statement$:
text = !warnIfNull
type = !void|Optional|int|boolean|long|char|short|byte

//Replace template for $Statement$:
WarnUtils.warnIfNull($Statement$)
```

WarnUtils:

```
@UtilityClass
public class WarnUtils {
    public <T> @NotNull T warnIfNull(@NotNull T t) {
        return t;
    }
}
```

I don't know how to make a template for multiline lambdas and I don't like wrapping all single-line lambdas with an additional method.

I think script filters may help, but I have no idea what to do with `__context__` to check whether lambda probably returns null.

Comment: Please provide a code sample where inspection Constant conditions & exceptions works incorrectly with lambda expressions. Thanks

Comment: @OlgaKlisho `Supplier<@NotNull Integer> supplier = () -> null;` - no warnings here. `if(supplier.get() == null)` - warning "_Condition 'supplier.get() == null' is always false_".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem can be solved without additional code inspections just by using functional interface which has `@NotNull` annotation on its abstract method.

For example, if you need a supplier which mustn't return null you can use this interface:

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface NotNullSupplier<T> {
    @NotNull
    T get();
}
```

If you try to return null from lambda expression of this type, *Constant conditions & exceptions* or *Return of 'null'* code inspection will detect it:

```
NotNullSupplier<Integer> supplier = () -> null; // warning - 'null' is returned by the method declared as @NotNull
```

---

I want to notice that using `Supplier<@NotNull T>` may lead to incorrect behavior of mentioned code inspections (it must be a bug which probably will be fixed later). Here is an example of such behavior:

```
Supplier<@NonNull Integer> supplier = () -> null; // no warnings
Integer result = supplier.get();
if(result != null) // warning - Condition 'result != null' is always 'true'
    result++;
```

*Constant conditions & exceptions* code inspection suggests to "*Unwrap 'if' statement*", following this advice in this case will lead to `NullPointerException`.

To avoid such mistakes you can add the following *Search Templates* to *Structural Search Inspection*:

```
//Search template:
Supplier<@NotNull $T$>
//Replace template:
NotNullSupplier<$T$>
```

```
//Search template:
Function<$T$, @NotNull $R$>
//Replace template:
NotNullFunction<$T$, $R$>
```

```
//Search template:
BiFunction<$T$, $U$, @NotNull $R$>
//Replace template:
NotNullBiFunction<$T$, $U$, $R$>
```